# SKLabelNode PhysicsBody Issue

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, physics, bezier, cgpath

The game [Supertype](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/supertype/id1349292121) is incredible.
I was thinking about making an app similar to it.
Is there any easy way to turn the text of a SKLabelNode into a Physics Body?

for example, I want to have the letter 'A' become a literal Physics Body
 - Is there any simplistic way to achieve this without having to actually define each cgPath?
 - I guess I could make the 'A' a SKSpriteNode, but this seems poor.

Also,
I've had many problems turning SKSpriteNodes into Physics Bodies. I can easily turn a single image into a physicsBody, but if it's an image broken apart by invisible segments, things brake. Swift chooses a specific segment to become a physicsBody.
 • I'm also so upset, since you can't define a concave shape and make a Physics Body. But you can have concave contiguous images become physics bodies nicely.

Last,,
It would be very nice to have a word turn into a Physics Body, and with a Boolean, define it to fall apart or stick together. Is there a way to do this?
(I'm thinking I can do it by clumping an array of them in the initialization: [SKPhysicsBody])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SKLabelNode` doesn't have a physics body, so you can not apply physics directly to it. What you could do is create them as a set of `SKSpriteNodes` and assign an image of each letter to the body texture.

To "turn the physics body on and off", you should toggle the node's property `isDynamic`. For other effects, you can play with `affectedByGravity` property and the collision and the contact bitMasks, depending on what you want.

To make the collision feel more real, you can use `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`, so you can automatically "draw" a physics body with the exact shape of the letters. Something like this:

```
letterNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: letterTexture, alphaThreshold: 1.0, size: letterTexture.size())
```

To handle the collisions and contacts, don't forget to set the contactDelegate in your scene, like this:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Comment: Ok sounds good. I had a feeling that I might need to use images. This means letters like ```i``` and ```j``` will require 2 sprites. I might go ahead and define their CGPaths to save memory and reduce complexity. It's unfortunate SVGs do not have this property.

Comment: @Jonathan you are probably going to have to create CGPaths for the physics regardless. Since iOS13 physicsBody via alpha transparency does not work as expected. It is a known bug. I personally use a program called PaintCode to create my complex paths, and it outputs the vector lines into code for you, probably save you days

Comment: @RonMyschuk thank you so much! I completely forgot about PaintCode, I think it will be very valuable! (I usually draw in vectors anyway, so this will be very useful)